# Excel - Tarifa eléctrica 3.0 española

Tags: excel, condiciones, clase-anidada

Necesito generar un código que me seccione por precios la tarifa eléctrica Española 3.0.

La tarifa tiene 6 precios:

> P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6

Y se divide en 4 temporadas:

| - | - |
| --- | --- |
| ALTA | ENERO, FEBRERO, JULIO, DICIEMBRE |
| MEDIA-ALTA | MARZO, NOVIEMBRE |
| MEDIA | JUNIO, AGOSTO, SEPTIEMBRE |
| BAJA | ABRIL, MAYO, OCTUBRE |

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, he seleccionado unos festivos que se establecen todo el horario en precio *P6*.

El código solo funciona en festivos horarios y en el primer bucle en temporada *Alta*.

El restos de bucles me indica *FALSO* exceptuando los sábados y domingos que si funcionan.

- [**EL FALLO.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6grTW.png)

Entiendo que tengo un fallo marcando horas (7:00 - 8:00) además de quizá aplicar `SI.CONJUNTO` o en anidar los bucles con los paréntesis.

Para los sábados y domingos he utilizado la formula `DIASEM(celda;2)>5`

```
=SI(O(A2=FECHANUMERO("1/1/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("6/1/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("19/3/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("14/04/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("15/04/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("18/4/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("28/04/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("23/06/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("24/06/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("15/08/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("9/10/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("12/10/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("1/11/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("6/12/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("8/12/2019");A2=FECHANUMERO("1/1/2020");A2=FECHANUMERO("6/1/2020");A2=FECHANUMERO("19/3/2020");DIASEM(A2;2)>5);
'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS'!$F$11;SI(O(MES(A2)=1;MES(A2)=2;MES(A2)=7;MES(A2)=12);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$6;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$6;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(O(MES(A2)=3;MES(A2)=11);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(O(MES(A2)=6;MES(A2)=8;MES(A2)=11);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(O(MES(A2)=4;MES(A2)=5;MES(A2)=11);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;0)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

- [**CÓDIGO Y COLUMNAS QUE TENGO.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq97O.png)
- [**PÁGINA CON VARIABLES DE PRECIOS.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJZ5.png)

He probado a modificar las horas y la parte 7:00-8:00 poner una celda con 8:00, pero me salta otro error y se me queda en falso todo intentando solucionar esto:

[**Fallo en cuestión.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QbJy.png)

```
=SI(O(A1825=FECHANUMERO("1/1/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("6/1/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("19/3/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("14/04/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("15/04/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("18/4/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("28/04/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("23/06/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("24/06/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("15/08/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("9/10/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("12/10/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("1/11/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("6/12/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("8/12/2019");A1825=FECHANUMERO("1/1/2020");A1825=FECHANUMERO("6/1/2020");A1825=FECHANUMERO("19/3/2020");DIASEM(A1825;2)>5);'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(O(MES(A1825)=1;MES(A1825)=2;MES(A1825)=7;MES(A1825)=12);SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("00:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("7:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(B1825=VALOR("08:00:00");'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("09:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("13:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$6;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("14:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("17:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("18:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("21:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$6;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("22:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(O(MES(A1825)=3;MES(A1825)=11);SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("00:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("7:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(B1825=VALOR("08:00:00");'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("09:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("13:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("14:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("17:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("18:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("21:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("22:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(O(MES(A1825)=6;MES(A1825)=8;MES(A1825)=11);SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("00:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("7:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(B1825=VALOR("08:00:00");'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("09:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("13:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("14:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("17:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("18:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("21:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("22:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(O(MES(A1825)=4;MES(A1825)=5;MES(A1825)=11);SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("00:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("7:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(B1825=VALOR("08:00:00");'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("09:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("13:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("14:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("17:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("18:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("21:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B1825>=VALOR("22:00:00");B1825<=VALOR("24:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;0)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en españo. Si bien la pregunta está muy bien documentada, no entiendo todavía qué problema concreto y específico tienes. ¿Cuál sería tu output esperado?

Comment: Muy buenas.Basicamente el problema es que el código enviado no funciona el segundo bucle (ahí foto en el programa ). Sólo funciona los meses de temporada alta el resto de meses marcaría como FALSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero un cambio en la estructura de tus datos, ya que te facilitaría **enormemente** la formulación. Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte de la derecha he puesto fórmulas individuales para explicar mejor el proceso, pero luego fusiono todas en una sola fórmula.

Verás que he creado estructuras adicionales, como a la izquierda donde relaciono temporadas y meses, o en la de los tramos, que tiene la columna de número de fila y una columna con todo P6 que es el tramo de los días festivos.

También he añadido una lista de días festivos con solo 2 fechas pero ampliable, y que facilita **muchísimo** formular si un día es festivo o no (tu fórmula es demasiado grande e incómoda porque picas cada día individual).

Dicho esto, vamos por partes. Desde aquí hablamos solo de las columnas naranjas:

**TEMPORADA**: Para ver si es festivo o qué temporada:

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI($P$2:$P$3;R2)>0;"FESTIVO";BUSCARV(MES(R2);$A$2:$B$13;2;FALSO))
```

Fíjate que al crear la lista de festivos, con solo `CONTAR.SI($P$2:$P$3;R2)>0;` ya lo compruebas. Solo con esto hemos reducido tu fórmula muchísimo.

**# FILA:** Para ver qué número fila interesa para sacar el tramo, según el horario:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($D$2:$D$7;$E$2:$E$7;"<="&S2;$F$2:$F$7;">"&S2)
```

Para que esto funcione, las horas de INICIO y FIN deben ser numéricas. Y ojo porque yo uso valores enteros (eso de 07:59 queda cutrecillo). El 00:00 de inicio es un cero a pelo, pero el 00:00 de FIN al final del todo es `=24/24`. Siempre que quieras meter una hora entera en excel, haz `hora/24`. Por ejemplo, las 09:00 sería `=9/24` y aplícale formato hora. Será un número que Excel puede calcular pero visto como hora.

**TRAMO:**: Para ver si es P1,P2,P3,P4,P5 o P6 según la temporada (o que sea festivo):

```
=INDICE($G$2:$K$7;U2;COINCIDIR(T2;$G$1:$K$1;0))
```

**kWh:** el precio final según el tramo:

```
=BUSCARV(V2;$M$2:$N$7;2;FALSO)
```

**FORMULA COMPLETA:** la fusión de todas las funciones anteriores en 1 sola para ahorrar columnas:

```
=BUSCARV(INDICE($G$2:$K$7;SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($D$2:$D$7;$E$2:$E$7;"<="&S2;$F$2:$F$7;">"&S2);COINCIDIR(SI(CONTAR.SI($P$2:$P$3;R2)>0;"FESTIVO";BUSCARV(MES(R2);$A$2:$B$13;2;FALSO));$G$1:$K$1;0));$M$2:$N$7;2;FALSO)
```

Fíjate que incluso la fusión final es notablemente más pequeña que tu fórmula. Así optimizas tiempos de cálculo y eficiencia.

También se podría incorporar que mire un precio según la tarifa sea + o - 10 kWh con la función ELEGIR, pero como ejemplo inicial te puede servir.

He subido el ejemplo a Gdrive por si quieres descargarlo y ver las funciones tú mismo. Mira bien cómo he metido las horas en la parte amarilla!!!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13LhXo0bKpZsIptWnkgr8LAkL2-fmDfAF/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104533162415852069785&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Esei primero de todo mil gracias por la respuesta tan rápida. Lo acabo de aplicar a mi hoja y funciona ya correctamente todo, muchas gracias por dejarla desgranada para una mejor compresión de la fórmula es brutal, no conocía las formulas arrays en excel. Una maravilla vaya, ya puedo seguir realizando mi excel con este paso. Gracias por todo!